# Is it safe or possible to change SQL Server AutoGrowth when in a SQL Server AlwaysOn Cluster

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2016, auto-growth

I am wondering it is possible or advisable to change the AutoGrowth settings of a database while it is part of an AlwaysOn SQL Server 2016 database cluster. I realized I used the default settings when I want to use custom growth rates based on the suggestions by Brent Ozar.

[image: File Details]

I cant change them in the GUI so I am guessing its not possible but I wanted to check. Will I have to remove the database from the AlwaysOn group, change the growth settings and then add it back in?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have AutoGrow enabled and do it on the primary replica. You can also do it in t-sql using the ALTER DATABASE command.